# UIImageView performance issue with generated image

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm having some problems with updating the image of an UIImageView. I use a base image, that I modify by drawing in it before displaying. When displaying without the "overlay", performance is fine. But when I generate the "overlay", it takes close to 10 seconds before the view is updated. The base image is a 640x430 PNG file. I don't see any spikes in CPU and / or memory usage when the image is supposed to display - so I'm not really sure why it's taking so long. If I change the image to some static image bundled in my app, it changes instantaneously. Am I doing anything obviously stupid here?

The code I use to generate the overlay looks like this:

```
func drawTextOverlay(textData:[String : [CGFloat]], sourceImage:UIImage)->UIImage {
    log.debug("Overlay generation started")

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sourceImage.size);
    sourceImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,sourceImage.size.width,sourceImage.size.height));

    for letter in textData {
        let toDraw = letter.0
        let pointX = letter.1[0]
        let pointY = (letter.1[1])

        let rect = CGRectMake(pointX, pointY, sourceImage.size.width, sourceImage.size.height)
        let textStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle().mutableCopy() as NSMutableParagraphStyle
        textStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        let textColor = UIColor.redColor()

        let font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(12);
        let textFontAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle]

        toDraw.drawInRect(rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
    }

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    log.debug("Overlay generated")
    return newImage;
}
```

and it gets called like this:

```
self.imageView.image = self.drawOverlay(UIImage(named:"base_image")!)
self.imageView.setNeedsDisplay()

private func drawOverlay(image:UIImage)->UIImage {
    return graphicsService.drawTextOverlay(getKeys(), sourceImage: image)
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Making sure to post the notification to the main thread like this did the trick:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationName", object: nil)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it takes close to 10 seconds before the view is updated

Those words almost always mean that you are attempting to talk to the interface from a background thread. You must never do that.

Comment: Well, I'm doing this as a response to a notification from NSNotificationCenter. Are these processed by a separate thread automatically?

Comment: Making sure to post the notification to the main thread solved this. Thanks!